# Find conditions on α and β that ensure that Null(A) = {0} and Find conditions on α and β that ensure that Col(B) = R 3

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A and B be the matrices

$$
A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & α \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & β
 \\
    \end{pmatrix} ,B = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & β \\
    α & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 3 & α
 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I've managed to reduce both matrices to its echelon form:

$$
    A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & α \\
    0 & 0 & β-2α \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and

$$
    B = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & β \\
    0 & 0 & α-3β \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I can't seem to form a linear system of equations with α and β separate from each other so I can find values for them.

Any kind of help is appreciated!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

To make sure that the nullity only consist of the zero vector, make sure that $A$ is nonsingular.

To make sure that the column space of $B$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$, also make sure that $B$ is nonsingular.

That is we require their RREF to be nonsingular, or equivalently, every column has a pivot element.

Hint:

> I expect to see "$\ne 0$" in your condition. There are two conditions and you are not suppose to find their numerical values.

Comment: Ah! Am I wrong to have the final answers as β-2α ≠ 0 and α-3β ≠ 0 so the matrices are non singular?

Comment: you got it. congratulations. try to learn how to type in mathjax, try to surround, \beta, \alpha, \ne with dollar sign and see what do you get. here's a [mathjax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553)